# HTML Canvas: ctx.stroke restroke behaviour with transparent colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am working on a sketch tool with html canvas.

I am using a common algorithm for this, that uses the mousedown, mousemove, mouseup events.

**mousedown**
    I `beginPath()`, and `moveTo(// the mouse coordinates)`.

**mousemove**
   I draw `lineTo(// the mouse coordinates)`, and then `stoke(// the line to render it)`

**mouseup**
   I do nothing, `// closePath()`

And I noticed that, calling the stroke method without first calling closePath or beginPath, will redraw or restroke all previous paths or lines, which makes them appear thicker than the define color.

without a transparent color its is barely noticeable, but the colors do appear thicker than they should be.

but with color with transparency|alpha e.g. rgba(). The most recent path or line respects the color's transparency, but all previous line due to the redraw, the transparent colored line overlap and that causes previous lines to get thicker in sequence or succession.

is there a way to avoid|prevent this behavior. thank in advance.
sample is below, try drawing really fast!

```js
var cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
    cvs.width = cvs.parentElement.clientWidth;
    
var colorInput = document.querySelector("input");
    
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"
ctx.lineWidth = 20;

onDraw(cvs, {

    penDown: function(e) {
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        
        ctx.strokeStyle = colorInput.value;
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    },
    
    penMove: function(e) {
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    
    penUp: function() {
        // ctx.closePath;
    }

});


function onDraw(node, drawHandler, beginHandler, endHandler, outOfBoundHandler, sticky) {
  var mouseDown = false, mouseOut = false;

  if( typeof drawHandler === "object" ) {
   var drawEvents = drawHandler;

   drawHandler = get(drawEvents.penMove);
   beginHandler = get(drawEvents.penDown);
   endHandler = get(drawEvents.penUp);
   outOfBoundHandler = get(drawEvents.penOff);
   sticky = drawEvents.sticky;
  }

  function get(name) {
   return typeof name === "string" ? drawEvents[ name ] : name;
  }

  node.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
   mouseDown = true;
   beginHandler&&beginHandler.call(this, e);
  });

  node.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
   mouseDown&&drawHandler&&drawHandler.call(this, e);
  });

  node.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
   mouseDown = false;
   endHandler&&endHandler.call(this, e);
  });

  node.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
   mouseDown&&outOfBoundHandler&&outOfBoundHandler.call(this, e);

   if( !sticky ) {
    mouseDown = false;
   }
  });
 }
```

```css
.wrapper { border: 1px solid #aaa }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <canvas border="1" width="600" hieght="400">Canvas is not supported</canvas>
    <input type="text" value="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)" placeholder="rgba(#, #, #, #)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no Path argument is passed to `stroke` and `fill` methods they will use the path currently being declared with the context's drawing methods.

```js
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
// starts Path declaration
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(30, 80);

ctx.stroke(); // first rendering

setTimeout(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150); // even if we clear the canvas
  ctx.lineTo(70, 20); // this will continue path declaration

  setTimeout(() => {
    ctx.stroke(); // and this will draw everything
  }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

The only ways to start a new path declaration (except for the first one) are to either reset the whole context (not good), or to use `beginPath` method.

```js
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
// starts Path declaration
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(30, 80);

ctx.stroke(); // first rendering

setTimeout(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
  ctx.beginPath(); // start a new Path declaration
  ctx.moveTo(30, 80); // we need to move to the previous coords
  ctx.lineTo(70, 20); // this will be alone
  ctx.stroke(); // and this will draw only the new path
}, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

About `closePath`, it's just a `lineTo(last_point_in_current_path_declaration)`, and doesn't ends a path declaration in no way.

So for your problem, there are two strategies you can adopt :

- keep only the last coordinates, and at every mousemove,

  ```
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
  ctx.lineTo(nextX, nextY);
  ```

- keep all your coordinates in an array and redraw everything every time

  ```
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  coords.forEach(pt => ctx.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y));
  ctx.stroke();
  ```

Personally, I prefer the second one, which allows some undo - redo, and to e.g change your pen's style.

Comment: wow! i am actually using the second method for my sketch tool which is very flexible but continuous draw expecially with a huge lineWidth, begins to lag the app and performance drops.

Comment: After a `ctx.beginPath()` the first `ctx.lineTo`  acts like a `moveTo` which can simplify the rendering of arrays of points, removing the moveTo  and all the conditional checks on `i`. Eg `ctx.beginPath(); coords.forEach(p => ctx.lineTo(p.x,p.y)); ctx.stroke();`